# Counting all and selecting single row from joined table

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables: `users`, `posts`, and `likes`

I want to receive a total count of 'likes' for that post but also the id of the `like` if it exists.

Do I need the 2 JOINS for the same table? Or is there a more efficient way

```
SELECT p.id, u.username, p.message, count(DISTINCT l.id) AS likeCount, l2.id AS likedID
    FROM posts p
    INNER JOIN users u ON p.userID = u.id
    LEFT JOIN likes l ON p.id = l.postID
    LEFT JOIN likes l2 ON l2.userID = ? AND l2.postID = p.id
    WHERE p.status = 0
```

Comment: What does `p.status = 0` means?

Comment: just a variable that gets depicts if it should be: visible, has been deleted or is pending review, irrelevant to the question, my mistake for leaving it in